# DNS for restricting youtube content

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

Google sent out an email to Admins stating that they were no longer supporting YouTube for Schools. Instead, they say, if we want restricted content we should:

> Configure Domain Name System (DNS) on your network so that
>   restrict.youtube.com is a Canonical Name (CNAME) for the following
>   hostnames:
>
> - www.youtube.com
> - m.youtube.com
> - youtubei.googleapis.com

I'm using Microsoft DNS and I can create the domains `youtube.com` and `googleapis.com` with no problem. The problem that I am running into is creating two `restrict.youtube.com` `CNAMEs` for `www.youtube.com` and `m.youtube.com`. My research indicates that this is a violation of the RFC's and Microsoft DNS will not allow it. Any idea how to perform what Google requires? I can't create `A` recs for `www.youtube.com` and `m.youtube.com` and point them to `restrict.youtube.com` because they require an IP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Not familiar with MS DNS, but it seems that you should do the opposite of what you are doing.
I mean, you are probably doing:

```
restrict.youtube.com. CNAME www.youtube.com.
restrict.youtube.com. CNAME m.youtube.com.
```

Which means that "`restrict.youtube.com` have the same IP address as `www.youtube.com` AND `m.youtube.com`". Probably you want the opposite:

```
www.youtube.com. CNAME restrict.youtube.com.
m.youtube.com. CNAME restrict.youtube.com.
```

which means "`www.youtube.com` and `m.youtube.com` will use the same IP address as `restrict.youtube.com`"

Answer (score -1):

***To add an alias (CNAME) resource record to a zone using the Windows interface
Open DNS Manager.***

- In the console tree, right-click the applicable forward lookup zone, and then click New Alias.
- In Alias name, type the alias name.
- In Fully qualified domain name (FQDN) for target host, type the FQDN of the DNS host computer for which this alias is to be used.
- As an option, you can click Browse to search the DNS namespace for hosts in this domain that have host (A) resource records already defined.
- Click **OK** to add the new record to the zone.

Or if you want to edit the zone file:

```
www.youtube.com CNAME restrict.youtube.com. // For Desktop Version of Youtube

m.youtube.com CNAME restrict.youtube.com.  // For Mobile Version of Youtube
```

Comment: Since this is now fixed, I removed my downvote.